# Ignoring tracked items from the repository

Tags: mercurial

I have a `mercurial` project of my website. I have `symlinked` (`Mac OS X aliases`) lot of files from here `to elsewhere. I made a mistake to add and commit all the aliases in my repository too.

However now I want to keep them untracked, so I added an entry in my `.hgignore` -

```
syntax:glob

*.pdf
*alias

[... snipped ...]
```

But I still see them when I do `hg status`

```
$ hg status

M documents/.../x alias
M documents/.../y alias
M documents/.../z alias

[... snipped ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell hg to remove or forget these files, because right now they are still in your repository, and hg won't ignore files that it's already tracking--it will just ignore files that aren't already tracked.

Comment: just to add: to remove the tracked files in your current `.hgignore` use: `$ hg remove -f "set:hgignore()"`